# Error while creating a python file executable

Tags: python, nuitka

I have been using nuitka to compile python to create executable so that I do not have to share the source code with others. While this has been working well, recently I ran into issues with python programs using pandas

When I run the following command:
nuitka --recurse-on et.py

I get a warning:
Nuitka:WARNING:et.py:4: Cannot find 'pandas' as relative or absolute import.

But it goes ahead and create a et.exe file. While I try to run this exe file ( ./et.exe), I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/babujia/exceltest/et.py", line 4, in 
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas

I am using Google Cloud Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3.5.2

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use pyinstaller, see here: **https://www.pyinstaller.org/**
To use it, open the **terminal** , and type **pip install pyinstall** to intall pyinstaller on your mechine. Then, open the terminal **under the python file you desired to become executable file**, and then write: **pyinstaller --onefile yourfileName.py
.** It will create 3 folders. Your'e EXE file is under **dist**. That's it, it's ready to use.

Comment: I did the following: sudo pip install pyinstall and pyinstaller --onefile et.py. But got the following error : pyinstaller: command not found

Comment: This is the confirmation of pyinstall installation :   Running setup.py install for pyinstall ... done
Successfully installed pyinstall-0.1.4

Comment: You installed "pyinstall" instead of "pyinstaller".